# Как можно заменить pow?

Tags: c, математика

Как можно переписать программу так, что бы в ней не использовался pow, но происходило все тоже самое?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

//держит один бит
struct sbit
{
    unsigned b : 1;
};

typedef struct sbit BIT;

float getMantissa(BIT* mantissa)
{
    int i;
    float sum = 1;
    for (i = 22; i > -1; i--)
        sum += (pow(2, i - 23) * (int)(mantissa[i].b));
    return sum;//*4; //2^2
}

int porydok(BIT* expo)
{
    int i;
    float sum = 0;
    //перевдим binary char в int
    for (i = 7; i > -1; i--)
        sum += (pow(2, i) * (int)(expo[i].b));

    return (int)(sum - 127);
}

int main()
{
    BIT* bit;
    BIT* mantissa;
    BIT* expo;
    BIT* sign;
    int isign;
    float data;
    int dataBits;
    int i;
    //выделяем 32 бита памяти
    bit = (BIT*)calloc(32, sizeof(BIT));
    //выделяем 23 бита для мантиссы
    mantissa = (BIT*)calloc(23, sizeof(BIT));
    //выделяем 8 бит для характеристики 
    expo = (BIT*)calloc(8, sizeof(BIT));
    //1 бит для знака
    sign = (BIT*)calloc(1, sizeof(BIT));
    printf("Enter number:"); scanf_s("%f", &data);
    //преобразовать данные с плавающей точкой в int
    dataBits = *(int*)&data;
    //поместите биты с плавающей запятой в структуру битов
    for (i = 0; i < 32; i++)
        //переполнение правй части
        bit[i].b = (dataBits << (32 - (i + 1))) >> 31;
    //печатаем биты с плавающей запятой
    printf("Floating point: \t");
    for (i = 31; i > -1; i--)
        printf("%d", (int)(bit[i].b));
    printf("\n");
    printf("Mantissa: \t\t");
    for (i = 0; i < 23; i++)
        mantissa[i].b = (dataBits << (32 - (i + 1))) >> 31;
    for (i = 22; i > -1; i--)
        printf("%d", (int)(mantissa[i].b));
    printf("\nHaracteristik: \t\t");
    for (i = 23; i < 31; i++)
        expo[i - 23].b = (dataBits << (32 - (i + 1))) >> 31;
    for (i = 29; i > 21; i--)
        printf("%d", (int)(expo[i - 22].b));
    printf("\nSign:\t\t\t");
    sign[0].b = dataBits >> 31;
    printf("%d\n", (int)(sign[0].b));
    isign = ((int)sign[0].b == 1) ? -1 : 1;
    printf("Porydok:\t\t%d", porydok(expo));
    printf("\n%.16f\n ", isign * getMantissa(mantissa) * pow(2,
        porydok(expo)));
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

А какая разница?

У вас показатель степени целый. Ну, чтоб быстрее работало, не циклом, а за O(log N) -

```
long long qpow(int x, int e)
{ 
    long long res = 1;
    for(;e;e>>=1)
    {
        if (e&1) res *= x;
        x *= x;
    }
    return res;
}
```

Это если показатель степени больше 0. Если меньше нуля - пользуемся тем, что a<sup>-b</sup> = 1/a<sup>b</sup>.

Но! это для общего случая. В вашем же конкретном случае вы просто 2 возводите в степень i. Что легко получается операцией сдвига `1 << i`... :)

Это вас устроит?

P.S. А чем, кстати, `pow` не угодила?

Comment: Преподаватель сказал, что при использовании pow точность сбивается. Спасибо за предложение идеи со сдвигом, но теперь возникает проблема, что числа по типу 0.1 вычисляются неверно. Как это можно исправить?

Comment: `pow` не угодила, видимо, тем, что если преподаватель увидит такой код, он захочет взять линейку и ударить ею ученика по пальцам. Но и ваш ответ я бы тоже не принял, потому что там возведение в степень идёт в цикле, то есть каждая следующая итерация может быть получена из предыдущей однократным сдвигом

Comment: @Zealint Поясните. Пока что я вам понял так, что нужно хранить значение 2^i из предыдущей итерации, и сдвигать его на 1? Чем это лучше сдвига на i? Неужто настолько быстрее, что становится важным?

Comment: Вопрос о "числах по типу 0.1" не понял; в любом случае - это уже совсем другой вопрос. Одно дело - бегом ответить на то, как переписать `pow`, и другое - разбираться в программе, о которой даже неизвестно, что она должна делать - почему она это делает неверно. Откуда же мне знать, что в ней неверно, если я не знаю, что такое верно? :)

Comment: @Harry , размер машинной команды должен быть разным, хотя я этого не проверял, но есть ещё "правила хорошего тона", которые гласят, что не нужно делать всякую фигню, когда есть очевидно более красивое решение. В любом случае, моё личное чувство эстетики требует сделать именно сдвиг на 1. Но я вам плюс поставил :) В целом-то правильно ответили.